# change input HTML in chrome automatically

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

is it possible in chrome when if am in specific website if it have input with type password it automatically change it to text ?

the purpose of this is because I always want to see the password I am typing.

thanks for helping

Comment: you can make your own chrome extension. That's the purpose of chrome extensions.you can find plenty of tutorial on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend downloading the extension [tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) that allows you to run JavaScript code on all the pages you want.

You can then create your own script to do what you want, or take one from GitHub:

like this one that seems to do what you want:
https://gist.github.com/LouCypher/1870154

**to download the script** just click on the raw button on gist after installing the extension, tampermonkey will automatically recognise the script and propose you to download it.